# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable, Maximum Pairwise Product

Tags: python, pythomnic3k

when I Run this function I get this error, I don't know where is the problem ?

```
def max_product(number):
    n = len(number)
    indexMax1 = 0
    indexMax2 = 0
    for f in range(n):
        if f > number[indexMax1]:
            indexMax1 = number.index(f)
    for s in range(n):
        if(s > number[indexMax2] and indexMax2 != indexMax1):
            indexMax2 = number.index(s)
    return number(indexMax2)*number(indexMax1)
```

Comment: number(indexMax2)*number(indexMax1) should be with [] and not with ()

Comment: Assuming number is list, the call number(indexMax2) should use square brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the error is in the last line

```
return number(indexMax2)*number(indexMax1)
```

You are trying to call number(indexMax2) and number(indexMax1). I think what you wanted to do is multiply elements of number with indices indexMax2 and indexMax1. You need to change the brackets to square brackets:

```
return number[indexMax2]*number[indexMax1]
```

Please specify the types of input variables in your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_product(number):
    n = len(number)
    indexMax1 = 0
    indexMax2 = 0
    for f in range(n):
        if f > number[indexMax1]:
            indexMax1 = number.index(f)
    for s in range(n):
        if(s > number[indexMax2] and indexMax2 != indexMax1):
            indexMax2 = number.index(s)
    return number[indexMax2]*number[indexMax1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As Lior Cohen stated in his comment, this is just a matter of parenthesis instead of brackets. The correct code is:

```
def max_product(number):
    n = len(number)
    indexMax1 = 0
    indexMax2 = 0
    for f in range(n):
        if f > number[indexMax1]:
            indexMax1 = number.index(f)
    for s in range(n):
        if(s > number[indexMax2] and indexMax2 != indexMax1):
            indexMax2 = number.index(s)
    return number[indexMax2]*number[indexMax1]
```